# Oracle Java stored librairies won't compile

Tags: java, oracle11g, java-stored-procedures, loadjava

I'm looking to store Java libraries inside my Oracle database. Note that this is the first time I'm doing that. That library is pd4ml. It is made up of two jars, which contains the compiled classes.

- `pd4ml.jar`
- `ss_css2.jar` (required by pd4ml.jar)

As loading them with Toad did not work (Toad said they were loaded successfully, but did they not show up anywhere) I went command line (loadjava) and managed to load `ss_css2.jar` successfully. All its classes were loaded and compiled.

The second library, `pd4ml.jar`, was also loaded, but several classes won't compile. I ran ojvmtc to try to resolve references. I got the following message:

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper
>
> org/zefer/pd4ml/npdf/parser/c

The first one, if my understanding is correct, should be part of the JRE that is built-in 11g r2. Browsing the `sys` schema, it does not appear to exist.

The second one is part of the jar library. Now I'm not exactly sure of the structure of compiled Java, I've never had to look into it before, but I have several .class files inside `org/zefer/pd4ml/npdf/parser/`, these being: `c$_b`, `c$_c`.... to `c$_g`. There is none that is only `c`.

The library works well on my local machine when passing command line arguments or running it from Eclipse, so it should work. There is no specific error message that shows up when trying to compile them in Toad. I have a feeling it's a dependencies/classpath issue.

Any hints on how I should ensure that classes contained in `pd4ml.jar` can properly access  those in `ss_css2.jar` , or any potential causes to investigate? Perhaps a way to get detailed error messages from the Java code?

Comment: Try loading from command line using `loadjava` command, might give more details about errors. [This](http://shilpaviswanath.blogspot.com/2012/03/java-stored-procedures-and-load-java.html) article might be of some help. And try [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/preloading-a-java-library-in-db2-similar-to-oracles-loadjava) too

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a81358/02_load3.htm) for loadjava command from command line. When you do first time, you might experience different issues. So better use debug option on

Comment: I have used loadjava without much more success (I mentionned "going command line" in my original post, which might not have been clear - I've edited).

Using the `-verbose` command has given me serveral `ORA-2953` without any more detailed information: they are the same that show up as invalid in Toad.

Comment: Have you tried using debug option while loading jar files?

Comment: Yes. It gives me several `ORA-29534` or `ORA-29519` on classes within the library, as well as one `ORA-29521` on `javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper`.

Comment: What I remember of using loadjava is all dependent jar files must be available and try using -resolve option along with debug while loading jar files.

Comment: Both done along with `-fileoutput` (very handy to refer/check the errors) alas without managing to resolve the issue.

I should add that I tried using the `-genmissing` option, which does get rid of the `ORA-29534` or `ORA-29519` but gives me Java errors (NoSuchMethod) instead.

Comment: Glad to know you have progressed thus far. All permissions are being executed I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The strange class names like c$_b, c$_c.... to c$_g are result of JAR file obfuscation. The obfuscation impacts only non-public classes, so it should not harm.

As I see, in your particular case javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper class is missing (and probably few more) - the classes can be found in servlet-api.jar. Just take the file from any J2EE (or Tomcat) distribution and add the file to your project/application.

In usual scenarios the servlet-api classes are required only when WebApp-specific PD4ML methods are called. And the methods are called only when pd4ml.jar is a part of a web application (that means servlet-api.jar is among the application resources).

As I see now, Oracle database Java sub-system scans for all referenced resources (even if they are not needed in a scenario) and panic if anything is missing.